# How to inherit a class from another file/module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

I have two classes and am trying to inherit the class in one file from the class in another. However, my problem occurs when I try to put `account_validation` in another file, and inherit it in my `PageTwo` class. I am subject to the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stecd\Desktop\NEA - topLevel - client server\Frontend - Copy.py", line 1949, in <module>
    customerEnd = selfService()
  File "C:\Users\stecd\Desktop\NEA - topLevel - client server\Frontend - Copy.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.frame = F(self.container, self)
  File "C:\Users\stecd\Desktop\NEA - topLevel - client server\Frontend - Copy.py", line 91, in __init__
    validation.account_validation.__init__(self)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'parent' and 'controller'
```

My code:

```
#Inheriting class from same file attempt
#file.py
class account_validation():
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'test2'

class PageTwo(tk.Frame, 
    validation.account_validation):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        account_validation.__init__(self)
        print(self.test)


#inheriting class from another file
#validation.py
class account_validation():
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'test2'

#file.py
import validation
class PageTwo(tk.Frame, account_validation):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        account_validation.__init__(self)
        print(self.test)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the *entire error message including the stack trace*

Comment: I have added the stack trace error in. This is as minimal as I can go

Comment: To simplify matters, I just want to know how to inherit a class from another file

Comment: The way you *always* inherit a class, the fact that it is defined in another module **makes absolutely no difference** You have **not** added the stack trace, btw. Note, it need to be a *complete example*. I need to be able to copy and paste your code and reproduce your exact error, otherwise it is not "reproducible". Again, your example makes no sense, and the comments seem to be reversed.

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. You're not passing in the required parameters when creating an instance. This really has nothing to do with modules or files.

Comment: What parameter would I need to pass into my  account_validation.__init__? line

Comment: @grimReaperZ that isn't the line throwing the error, again, **provide the full stack trace** and an actual, reproducible example. You never actually use your class (which is the source of the error) so there's no way to say why you are getting the error other than you are instantiating it incorrectly.

Comment: I have added the full stack trace. Sorry. I didn't know that you wanted the whole error

Comment: You still aren't showing code that's actually causing the error to occur. In other words, a file with something like `customerEnd = selfService()` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from  the same file.

```
import tkinter as tk

class account_validation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'test'

class PageTwo(tk.Frame, account_validation):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        account_validation.__init__(self)
        print(self.test)

parent = tk.Tk()
page = PageTwo(parent, 'test')

parent.mainloop()
```

Inheriting from a different file. Assuming it's in the same path and under the name `validation.py`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from validation import account_validation

class PageTwo(tk.Frame, account_validation):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        account_validation.__init__(self)
        print(self.test)

parent = tk.Tk()
page = PageTwo(parent, 'test')

parent.mainloop()
```

and in the file `validation.py`.

```
class account_validation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'test'
```